# Force upload Bookmarks to Google Chrome sync

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks, xmarks

I was using X-Marks Bookmarks manager, but now this project is closed.

I tried default Google Chrome sync, but mistakenly I pressed sort bookmarks in bookmarks manager. This corrupted data was uploaded to server. Now I`ve restored my bookmarks from backup html file. But if I enable sync - chrome do force overwrite with corruped bookmarks from server.

Is there way to force upload my restored version?
Or maybe some alternate bookmarks manager?

Comment: Backup your current bookmarks, sync your profile, if you end up with the corrupted bookmarks delete them and sync the changes then import your backup and sync the changes

Comment: Tried this, but on second sync it just override my local bookmarks again.